# How do I use JQuery load to retrieve two sets of data in a single go

Tags: jquery

I'm using the JQuery load method to retrieve an HTML fragment from an external page. I then immediately call that page again to retrieve a different fragment. This works, but seems wasteful.

Can someone suggest a better way?

```
$('#basket').load('loadCart.php #cartContents', function() {
  $("#basket").slideDown("slow");

}); 

  $('#cartBar p').load('loadCart.php #cartHeading');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use the "," operator in the selector to select multiple elements?

```
$('#basket').load('loadCart.php #cartContents,#cartHeading', function() {
  $("#basket").slideDown("slow");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around this problem uses the $.ajax method and involves retrieving the whole html response. I parse the html using $(r) so that jquery can use it's usual selector functions. The I stored the parts I want in variables and place them into the corresponding container elements.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'yourFile.php',
    success: function(r){
      var element1 = $(r).find('#element1').html();//get the contents of #element1
      var element2 = $(r).find('#element2').html();//get the contents of #element2

      $('#container1').html(element1);//put html in container1
      $('#container2').html(element2);//put html in container2
    }
});
```

Hope this helps mate!

W.

Comment: Note that instead of collapsing the DOM to HTML, and then rebuilding it again, you can use the `.replaceWith()` method.  Target the whole element rather than the container, or just replace the whole container.  eg. `$('#container1').replaceWith($(r).find('#container1'));` (better not to do it in a one-liner like that, you should check it exists first).  The other advantage of that, is you can make modifications to it and retrieve information from it, before adding it to the DOM.

Comment: This looks like it should work but its not. I've tried alerting the values element1 and element2 and they display NULL. Alerting the value for r displays the valid HTML that I'm expecting. Any idea?